# logstash with multiple kafka topic input

Tags: logstash

I would like to start a logstash instance with following setting:

```
input {
  kafka {
    topic_id => "topic_a"
    .......
  }
  kafka {
    topic_id => "topic_b"
    .......
  }

}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  uuid {
    target => "@uuid"
  }
  mutate {
    replace => { "message" => "%{message}" } # want to get the full json literal but does not work
    add_field => {
      "topic" => "%{topic_id}" # it does not work either
    }
  }

  # logic to apply different filter base on topic_id
  if [topic_id] =~ 'topic_a' { # this block seems never entered        
    mutate {
       replace => { "topic" => "topic_a" }
    }
  } else {
    .....
  }
}
output {
  .....
}
```

The output on my Kibana would should something like below:

```
topic : %{topic_id}
```

It suggested that the configuration above could not extract the topic_id.
I have no idea on how to configure the filter part. Could anyone give a hint on this? Thanks.

BTW I'm using logstash-2.2.2

Edit: updated config according to logstash document, result still the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Kafka Input Plugin do not include metadata  info like:  topic_id ..
You have to enable `decorate_events` options:

```
kafka {
    topic_id => "topic_a"
    decorate_events => true
  }
```

When this done, you can find your topic_id  in:  `kafka` array with `topic` key.

> decorate_events
>
> Value type is boolean Default value is false Option to add Kafka
>   metadata like topic, message size to the event. This will add a field
>   named kafka to the logstash event containing the following attributes:
>   msg_size: The complete serialized size of this message in bytes
>   (including crc, header attributes, etc) topic: The topic this message
>   is associated with consumer_group: The consumer group used to read in
>   this event partition: The partition this message is associated with
>   key: A ByteBuffer containing the message key
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-decorate_events

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field) for add_field shows a different syntax than the one you're using.  You might try it.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "foo_%{somefield}" => "Hello world, from %{host}" }
  }  
}
```

Comment: hi, I have updated my question. I was actually using "%" instead of "$", but it doesn't work.

Comment: If the [topic] field is still not being set, it's because either your input is not coming through one of the two inputs you've shown (where topic_id is set), or your conditional (if topic_id = xxx) is not true, or the mutate->replace fails (in which case the add_field will not run).  Or something else you're not showing.